# Is this kind of tag merge possible?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

The tag wiki for [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) says:

> Canvas is an drawing element introduced to web development with HTML5, but also exists in Android and WPF development. Use the more specific tags where possible.

I've seen many questions with both the tags [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) and [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) which do not have the more specific [html5-canvas](/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) tag.

[A quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+canvas) showed me that the same problem exists around the [android-canvas](/questions/tagged/android-canvas) tag.

Is it possible to do a kind of tag merge where a question that is tagged both html5 and canvas has the canvas tag replaced with the html5-canvas tag, and the same for android (unless the question is tagged both android and html5).

Answer (score 2):

Not currently, no.  Only developers, and maybe community managers, have this capability.

Bad tags have a high correlation to poor post quality.  So when the community asks for a tag to be burned, the answer is always *"fix the tags one at a time, and fix the posts that need fixing while you're fixing the tags."*

Comment: So it is possible?

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to bother one of the developers.  But, as I said, the Community Team prefers that we solve it one question at a time.

Comment: True. You must go easy on the superpings.